# Linq ForEach to delete in mvc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to delete multiple records using linq in my mvc application. I have written the following code

To store selected items in a list. I have written the following code

```
List<int> TaskIds = chkId.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

I have written the following code to delete multiple records

```
db.Generals.Where(d => d.IID == TaskIds.ForEach(p => db.Generals.Remove(p.IID)));
```

But Remove(p.IID) is not a correct syntax. How could I find the write ID value for remove. Any clue

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this one:

```
db.Generals.Where(d => TaskIds.Contains(d.IID)).Delete();
```

or

```
 db.Generals.Where(d => TaskIds.Contains(d.IID)).ToList().ForEach(db.DeleteObject);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Not getting "Delete" or "DeleteObject" reference.

Comment: sry, it is part of ObjectContext, not from DbContext.
Here you are with DbContext
`db.Generals.RemoveRange(db.Generals.Where(d => TaskIds.Contains(d.IID)));
db.SaveChanges();`

Or if you prefer with ForEach
`db.Generals.Where(d => TaskIds.Contains(d.IID)).ToList().ForEach(s => db.Generals.Remove(s));`

Answer (score 0):

Attach them and delete them. I assume IID is the key field.

```
foreach(int id in chkId.Select(x => int.Parse(x))
{
  var general = new General { IID = id };
  db.Generals.Attach(general);
  db.Generals.Remove(general);
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var modellist = db.mymodel.Where(s => s.ID == ID).ToList();

foreach (var removemodel in modellist )
{
   db.modellist.Remove(removemodel );
}
db.SaveChanges();
```